# System Identification - Mathematical expression for a signal

Tags: system

I am having problems to formulate the signal ***d[n]*** that is given in the image below. What I am not getting here is that the result imho should be a scalar but no matter what I do I always end up multiplying a vector, the filter ***F_2(z)***, with a scalar.

Given:

\begin{align*}
H(z) &= 3 + 2z^{-1} \\
F_1(z) = F_2(z) &= z^{-1} + 0.1z^{-2}
\end{align*}

[image]

The equation for ***d[n]*** should look something like this:

\begin{align*}
d[n] &= \mathbf{f_2}^T \cdot \big( \mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{w}[n] + \nu[n] \big)
\end{align*}

But as you can see, the result wouldn't be a scalar.

What am I missing here?

**Hint:** It appears that we might have to rearrange the filtes F1, F2 somehow. But I don't know how that can help me.

Comment: Maybe your vector multiplications are backwards resulting in a matrix rather than a scalar.

Comment: @Daniel I don't think this makes sense here. It is all about learning the adaptive system C(z) and minimising the error e[n] = d[n] - c^T x[n]

Comment: Well, no matter what, d[0] is scalar, d[1] is scalar, d[2] is scalar...

Comment: Perhaps your answer should be of the form d[n] = 3*w[n]+2*w[n-1].. or whatever it would be.. I think you only have to go back to w[n-3] to get a complete answer for d[n]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your upper path, the transfere function of \$H(z)\$ uses the actual input sample at time \$n_0\$ and the next sample at time \$n_{1}\$
Also, \$F_{2}(Z)\$ processes the delayed samples of \$H(z)\$. Therefore we need to define the input as a Matrix in form of delayed input vectors for \$H(z)\$

\$w[n]={\begin{bmatrix}
w_0 & w_{-1}\\ 
w_{-1} & w_{-2}\\ 
w_{-2} & w_{-3}
\end{bmatrix}}\$

For \$n_0\$ we get following expression:
\$d[n]=\mathbf{f_2}\cdot(\mathbf{w}[n] \cdot \mathbf{h^T}+ \mathbf{v}[n])\$

And this gives:
\$d[n]=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0.1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot(\begin{bmatrix}
w_0 & w_{-1}\\ 
w_{-1} & w_{-2}\\ 
w_{-2} & w_{-3}
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
3\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
v_0\\ 
v_{-1}\\ 
v_{-2}
\end{bmatrix})\$

which outputs a scalar for \$d[n]\$

Comment: Hi! Thanks, that appears to make a lot more sense than that what I got. I think you mean d[n] = .. instead of n[n] = .. The matrix you show here does make sense I think. But can you explain the way you arrived at it? First we'd have [w0, w-1]^T if we'd consider only H(z). But then F2(z) has 0*r[n] + 1*r[n-1] + 0.1*r[n-2] (where r[n] is just the result of the first filter) which gives me the values [[w0, w-1], [w-1], w-2], [w-2, w-3]], right?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I corrected it to d[n]. The filter H(z) processes two samples [w0,w-1] , [w-1,w-2], [w-2,w-3], [w-3,w-4] and so on, the second filter F2(z) processes three samples from H(z) also [H(n),H(n-1),H(n-2)], [H(n-1),H(n-2),H(n-3)] and so on. Those first tree samples were indeed [[w(n),w(n-1)],[w(n-1),w(n-2)],[w(n-2),w(n-3)]]

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help! Makes sense to me :)